# canvas rendering not smooth

Tags: javascript, canvas

For some reason my rendering stutters sometimes. As you can see here(http://sirius-btx.com/test/).
Use your arrow keys to move.
The bottom canvas is prerendered only once, the prerender will then be drawn on the main upper canvas every frame.

Here is my code thats gets called every frame:

```
var tick = (function() {
    var lastTimestamp = 0;

    return function(timestamp) {
        dt = (timestamp - lastTimestamp) / 1000;
        lastTimestamp = timestamp;

        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, self.resolution.width, self.resolution.height);

        var cameraPosition = camera.position;
        if(keys[37]) {
            cameraPosition.x -= 10 * dt;
        }
        if(keys[38]) {
            cameraPosition.y -= 10 * dt;
        }
        if(keys[39]) {
            cameraPosition.x += 10 * dt;
        }
        if(keys[40]) {
            cameraPosition.y += 10 * dt;
        }

        camera.position = cameraPosition;

        var tileSet = self.resource.get("tiles");

        ctx.save();
        // mapCamera starts at the same position as camera.
        // So (mapCamera.position - camera.position) is the offset we have to move.
        ctx.translate((mapCamera.position.x - camera.position.x) * 16, (mapCamera.position.y - camera.position.y) * 16);
        // mapCanvas is the prerendered canvas.
        ctx.drawImage(mapCanvas, -16, -16, self.resolution.width + 32, self.resolution.height + 32);
        ctx.restore();

        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    };
})();
```

I've been trying to figure out why its not 100% smooth, but I can't find a solution.
Someone has an idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

3 advices here :

• Call early requestAnimationFrame : with my modest testing , it showed that things were a bit smoother when rAF is the first function called. Most probably because it needs behind-the-scene work to get to work. Try it !
 • When using drawImage, coordinates will be rounded for you : you might want to do the rounding yourself, since it is 'floor' that is used, and that 'ceil' that gives smoother results.
 • Most importantly, you are using the DOM (divs or like) to show the mouse position / fps. Don't do this. use fillText on your canvas (or on some other visible canvas), because you can't be sure you cause a reflow/repaint when changing those values.

Comment: Did what you said, but it's still stuttering

Comment: In fact it feels smooth on my modestly powerful desktop / latest FF/Ch / latest Mac OS.

Comment: Thats weird, I tested it on 2 machines(arch linux) and got the same problem.